drawHierarchy broken - image too bright
EDIT1
I have created github repo to reproduce the issue
https://github.com/PrashantKT/ImageViewScreenShotIssue
it is just 2 page app to demonstrate the problem
I have this code to take screenshot of view:
extension UIView {
    func takeSnapshot(rect : CGRect? = CGRect.zero) -> UIImage? {
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: frame.size)
        var image = renderer.image { _ in drawHierarchy(in: bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true) }
        if let imageRect = rect, imageRect != CGRect.zero {
            let screenshotFrame = CGRect(x: imageRect.origin.x * UIScreen.main.scale, y: imageRect.origin.y * UIScreen.main.scale, width: imageRect.size.width * UIScreen.main.scale, height: imageRect.size.height * UIScreen.main.scale)
            let imageRef = image.cgImage!.cropping(to: screenshotFrame)
            image = UIImage.init(cgImage: imageRef!, scale: image.scale, orientation: image.imageOrientation)
        }
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
    
}

which was working fine until I updated to macOS 14.4.1 from 14.2.1
and to Xcode 15.3 from 15.0.
issue
From my Mac Catalyst app, if I try to take screenshot of imageView, the screenshot is brighter.

2)
If I try this method:
func takeSnapshotWithoutScale()  -> UIImage? {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.frame.size, false, 0)
    if let currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
        self.layer.render(in: currentContext)
    }
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newImage
}



This might be irrelevant but it is rather crazy to use both UIGraphicsImageRenderer and UIGraphicsEndImageContext as in your first example.

It is unclear what the point of your comparison is, as you are doing two completely different things.

@matt Thank you so much for looking into matter , I am stuck in this for days now
I can explain , I have scrollview with image + some other views + Scenekit View to render 3d model inside image
now i need to take screenshot of that full view , earlier versions 14.2 this method working fine , image  colors are the same ,
But now 14.4 Image is brighter colors are completely diff
Could you pls. guide me better way to counter this issue ?

@matt
This might be irrelevant but it is rather crazy to use both UIGraphicsImageRenderer and UIGraphicsEndImageContext as in your first example. –
---> Noted I will remove UIGraphicsEndImageContext it is not useful thanks

Main problem is screenshot image color changes !!!

Prashant Tukadiya. Replace this category (in your github example):
extension UIView {
  func takeSnapshot() -> UIImage? {
    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: frame.size)
    let image = renderer.image { _ in drawHierarchy(in: bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true) }
    
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
  }
}

with this one:
extension UIView {
  func takeSnapshot() -> UIImage? {
    let format = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat()
    format.preferredRange = .standard
    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: frame.size, format: format)
    let image = renderer.image { _ in drawHierarchy(in: bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true) }
    
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
  }
}


Amazing working fine
